# Insert into jsonb[] column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

With this table

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS actions (
    action_id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    inputs JSONB[] NOT NULL DEFAULT ARRAY[]::JSONB[]
)
```

I'm trying to insert this data

```sql
INSERT INTO actions (
    action_id,
    inputs
)
VALUES (
    '41fc94af-2f4e-424f-acde-641bb63f4b82',
    array['{"type":"string"}{"displayName":"Base OAuth URL","type":"string","description":"Base OAuth URL"}']::jsonb[]
);
```

But getting the error

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 7:                                 array['{"type":"string"}{"di...
                                              ^
DETAIL:  Expected end of input, but found "{".
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"type":"string"}{...
```

This also doesn't work

```sql
INSERT INTO actions (
    action_id,
    inputs
)
VALUES (
    '41fc94af-2f4e-424f-acde-641bb63f4b82',
    [{"type":"string"}{"displayName":"Base OAuth URL","type":"string","description":"Base OAuth URL"}]::jsonb[]
);
```

Comment: You are mixing types Postgres `array` and `jsonb`. Do you really want a Postgres `array` of `jsonb` objects or a JSON array of objects that is stored as `jsonb`?

Comment: Avoid `jsonb[]`, it's hard to index and confusing to deal with

Comment: I agree with the other two. `jsonb[]` never makes sense in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get you intentionr. For sure what you wrote inside `array[..]` is neither a single json nor an array of json.

If `{"type":"string"}` and `{"displayName":"Base OAuth URL","type":"string","description":"Base OAuth URL"}` are two different objects then you have to write:

```
array[
    '{"type":"string"}',
    '{"displayName":"Base OAuth URL","type":"string","description":"Base OAuth URL"}'
    ]::jsonb[]
```

Comment: That was it. bad json. Thanks for pointing it out.